# Visual Studio 2008 error persists after re-installation

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I cannot get a VS 2008 solution to compile on a clients' laptop with a fresh export of one of their repository projects. The error I am getting is as follows:

```
C1902: Program database manager mismatch; please check your installation
```

This issue persists even after uninstalling and re-installing Visual Studio 2008 after a reboot. I know it typically means a version mismatch between one of a few files, but the re-install should have taken care of that. Under what other circumstances would this error come up?

This is happening on Windows XP 32 bit. The only other thing I can think of is maybe it is picking up on some of the Visual Studio 2003 files (which is also installed on the laptop) but the VS .NET 2003 directories are not on the system path so this also should not be the issue.

Any assistance on this would be appreciated. Google has not yielded anything other than checking the versions of mspdbsrv.exe and applicable .dlls, which all do match on this system.

Comment: Can it be that an 'express' edition of visual studio was (or still is) installed on the computer? I've encountered a problem when trying to install VS2008 after an express edition was installed (and uninstalled), and after a great effort nothing helped but formatting the hard drive. Sounds a radical solution, but it was the only thing that helped.

Comment: There is no Express edition installed on the hard drive, however, that is not to say there has never been an Express edition installed on the hard drive. I can check with the client and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to reload the system to fix this issue. Hopefully a better answer than this comes along sometime.